# explicitly address log4 appender

Tags: java, log4j, appender

I want to use the logger in such a way that only a certain information about it is displayed. in my system there are already several appenders in use and I want an additional one which is not filtered by level but explicitly addressed during logging.

```
 <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
 <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
 <appender-ref ref="SPECIAL"/>
```

the "SPECIAL" appender creates a my needed log. is it possible to address the appender explicit and the standard logging entries should be suppressed for this.

Example what i need

```
logger.getAppender("SPECIAL").log("my special log info");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your best approach is to use [StringMatchFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/StringMatchFilter.html) to filter log messages based on some kind of marker. Here is some sample code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Example1 {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example1.class);
    // This should probably go into a general purpose constants class of some kind
    // but for simplicity of this example it's in here.
    private static final String SPECIAL_MARKER = "SPECIAL";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        logger.debug("debug from my.Example1");
        logger.info("info from my.Example1");
        logger.warn("warning from my.Example1");
        logger.error("error from my.Example1");
        logger.fatal("fatal from my.Example1");

        logger.info(SPECIAL_MARKER+" This goes in a special file");
    }
}
```

Here is the log4j properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=logs/special.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.R.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.R.filter.1.StringToMatch=SPECIAL
log4j.appender.R.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.R.filter.2=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
```

An alternative would be to add a logger configuration that references the appender and then use that logger name to create your logger. I find this less elegant as you would need to declare a second logger.

Example Java code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Example1 {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example1.class);
    private static final Logger specialLog = Logger.getLogger("special");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        logger.debug("debug from my.Example1");
        logger.info("info from my.Example1");
        logger.warn("warning from my.Example1");
        logger.error("error from my.Example1");
        logger.fatal("fatal from my.Example1");

        specialLog.info("This goes in a special file");
    }
}
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=logs/special.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.special=INFO, R, stdout
log4j.additivity.special=false
```

In the example above the "special" logger is used to generate output to the special log.